# Hiding images temporarily on a slide while editing

Tags: macos, keynote

I have some slides in a presentation where images appear on click in full screen. While creating and editing the slide, the image is always above the text and basically I have to move the picture somewhere for editing my text and finally move the image back in place.

Keynote 6.2.2 for OSX. I find that hiding/removing images for editing and adding them again is tedious.

Is there a better way in doing this?

Comment: Is there a reason why the image and text need to be on the same slide? How are your transitions set?  When the slides are presented, do the images and text appear together or one after the other?  If not together on the same view, perhaps separating them to different slides with the desired transition would work.  Maybe a little more information about what your end result should look like would help in determining a solution.

Comment: Actually this suggestion was to easy to think about it... I wanted to have everything on one slide, so the slide number stays the same. Is there a way to control the slide number by hand? In this case, this solution would be great.